# How to get list of text in div with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Is it possible to get a list of text of div if there is a lot of spans in div?

Comment: I think this can help: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/

Comment: This helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hey bud maybe provide an html code or the site and i might be able to help
not sure i fully understand but if u r using css selectors u can do something like this

```
response.css('<cssselector>::text').get()#for first /getall() for all
```